# I want to create a folder in given path without changing directory

Tags: batch-file

The below program is Change the given directory and create a folder "CE" is work fine.

```
@echo off
:Get_File
echo.
set /p p="Enter Journal-ID: "
set /p q="Enter Internal-ID: "
set /p r="If you want to copy the into Local Path (y/n): "
IF %r%==y (
set /p t="Enter Local Path: "
for %%F in (%t%) do cd %%~dpF
md CE
)
```

I want to create a folder in given path without changing directory. Below the code if i enter the local path some like "D:\Backup\" to create a folder "CE" in given local path.

```
@echo off
:Get_File
echo.
set /p p="Enter Journal-ID: "
set /p q="Enter Internal-ID: "
set /p r="If you want to copy the into Local Path (y/n): "
IF %r%==y (
set /p t="Enter Local Path: "
for %%F in (%t%) do md CE %%~dpF
)
```

Comment: Did you try simple string concatenation ? If you just want to create a directory with the name `CE` in the path you get from the user. Just use `md %t%CE` . This won't change your current working directory.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You only need to be *in* the directory if you try to create a *relative* path name, something like:

```
set idiotbasedir=d:\idiots
set newidiot=trump

cd /d %idiotbasedir%
mkdir %newidiot%
```

If you wanted to create the directory *without* changing your current directory, you can just concatenate the strings to form an *absolute* path. That second section above can be replaced with:

```
mkdir %idiotbasedir%\%newidiot%
```